# Entity Framework - DatabaseContext not adding new row to database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, rest

Ok so something happend and my initial seed suddenly stopped working,
at first my DatabaseInitializer class worked fine, this was the code:

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            //
            context.Cities.Add(
        new Cities() { cityDesc = "London" }
        );
            context.Cities.Add(
    new Cities() { cityDesc = "Bristol" }

    );

            context.Streets.Add(
                new Streets() { cityId = 1, streetDesc = "Ab"}
                );

            context.Streets.Add(
              new Streets() { cityId = 2, streetDesc = "Cd" }
              );

            context.Streets.Add(
              new Streets() { cityId = 1, streetDesc = "Ef" }
              );

            context.Parkings.Add(
              new Parkings() { cityId = 1, streetId = 1, startDate = "2018-01-17", endDate = "2018-01-17" }
              );

            context.Parkings.Add(
          new Parkings() { cityId = 1, streetId = 2, startDate = "2019-01-17", endDate = "2019-01-17" }
          );

            context.Parkings.Add(
         new Parkings() { cityId = 2, streetId = 3, startDate = "2018-01-17", endDate = "2018-01-17" }
         );



            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

My database had two cities, three streets and three parkings.
Now, if i add more parkings, nothing happens. And not only that, even if i remove some of the parkings or the streets, i still get the same JSON result - two cities, three streets and three parkings.
For some reason, either the seed method stopped working, or my database is "locked". The data simply stays the same.

Help? thanks

Edit: my models:

```
public class Parkings
        {
            [Key]
            public int parkId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string startDate { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string endDate { get; set; }

            public int cityId { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("cityId")]
            public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }


            public int streetId { get; set; }



        }


        public class Cities 
        {
            [Key]
            public int cityId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string cityDesc { get; set; }

                  public virtual ICollection<Streets> Streets { get; set; }

                    public virtual ICollection<Parkings> Parkings { get; set; }


        }

        public class Streets
        {
            [Key]
            public int streetId { get; set; }

            public int cityId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string streetDesc { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("cityId")]
           public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }


        }
```

Comment: Are your navigation properties setup correctly, and are you mapping via data annotations or EntityTypeConfigurations?

Comment: Also, are you sure you meant for your dates to be strings?

Comment: @dperish at the moment, yes

Comment: Where do you get your JSON results from? If you add data, do you remember to call SaveChanges()? If yes, what is written to the log? What happens when you send SQL manually to the DB?

Comment: Have you changed your model? The initializer seed() only runs when the database is recreated. Migration Seed() may be what you are looking for - that runs with every update database. You could also change your initializer to DropCreateAlways. See [here](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/)

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks !! that's solved my problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, setting the initializer to **DropCreateDatabaseAlways** fixed the issue